# WebPack in VS2015: How to configure a new pack?

Tags: visual-studio, webpack, aspnetcoretemplatepack

I've started with a template from [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ASPNETCoreTemplatePack) to have a running `angular2`+ `.net core` starting point. I didn't want to use `boostrap`, but `materialize-css`, so I removed the bootstrap package in `package.json`, instead I added `"materialize-css": "0.98.0",`

Then I edited the `webpack.config.vendor.js`, I removed bootstrap and added `materialize-css` to the "vendor" list.

Then I rebuilt everything, but it seems that `materialize-css` is still not present(cannot find its css classes). I tried to clear the browser cache, tried even to open on a brand new browser(edge), but still, no materialize-css classes.

What did I miss?

**EDIT**

Currently, my vendor list is the following:

```
    vendor: [
        '@angular/common',
        '@angular/compiler',
        '@angular/core',
        '@angular/http',
        '@angular/platform-browser',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
        '@angular/router',
        '@angular/platform-server',
        'angular2-universal',
        'angular2-universal-polyfills',
        'materialize-css',
        'es6-shim',
        'es6-promise',
        'jquery',
        'zone.js',
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing everything correctly, just need to do one thing slightly differently. In your `webpack.config.vendor.js`, instead of `materialize-css`, add `materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css` to the `vendor` array:

```
...
entry: {
    vendor: {
        ...
        'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css',
        ...
    }
}
```

This will include the css to your resulting bundle. If you also need fonts and js from materialize-css, you'll need to configure appropriate loaders, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/materialize-loader

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand, I've also by example jquery that is loaded and working, and I've only to indicate that I want to have "jquery". and it is working, I was thinking it was going to `bower.json` of the specified module and checking what was required, and if I check for materialize, I've the expected "bin/materialize.css and bin/materialize.js". It's weird to have to specify myself the full path of the css, because if the author of the package change its structure, it won't work anymore.  So why does it work for jquery, but not materialize-css ?

Comment: It's not weird, as a matter of fact, this is exactly how bootstrap is referenced in the original ASP.NET Core Template Pack - https://github.com/ligershark/CoreTemplatePack/blob/master/Templates/AspNetCoreAngular2/webpack.config.vendor.js#L30 jQuery is a JS library, not CSS, it's looked up in the node_modules folder automatically. CSS files, however, need to be referenced manually.

Comment: Oh I see, so If I've to load the JS and the css? I can just specify once `materialize-css`and once `materialize-css/bin/materialize.css`? How does it know which js file to load?

Comment: Precisely. As I said above, it knows to look in the node_modules folder for js files, by the package name.

Comment: Ok, I tried to add your line, but it doesn't seems to have any effect(at least, my html that was working with those styles doesn't get the style from the css, not sure how to check that the class is actually loaded or not)

Comment: If it helps, the current status of the web app is on github, you can find the vendor.cs here: https://github.com/jgrossrieder/PokerScrum/blob/master/AngularTest.Web2/webpack.config.vendor.js

Comment: In your `wwwroot/dist` folder there is a file called `vendor.css` that is generated as a result of the Webpack build. It has all classes like `.materialize-red ...` defined in it, which means the `materialize-css` library was successfully bundled. Do you see the file? It's referenced in the _Layout view and should be present in the browser.

Comment: No, I don't have any materialize-css class, and worse, I still have some bootstrap classes, it seems that this file has not been updated. When this "webpack" should occurs?

Comment: I even tried to rename this vendor.css to check if it was generated again, and currently it's not the case